# Error connection - Dspace 6.0

Tags: dspace

**I did the clean default installation of dspace 6.0 however when I start the tomcat server I will return the following error.**

```
2017-05-30 16:58:32,475 INFO  org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils @ Loading Flyway DB migrations from: filesystem:/dspace/etc/postgres, classpath:org.dspace.storage.rdbms.sqlmigration.postgres, classpath:org.dspace.storage.rdbms.migration
2017-05-30 16:58:32,497 INFO  org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.VersionPrinter @ Flyway 4.0.3 by Boxfuse
2017-05-30 16:58:32,538 INFO  org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory @ Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dspace (PostgreSQL 9.4)
2017-05-30 16:58:32,616 INFO  org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils @ DSpace database schema is up to date
2017-05-30 16:58:32,629 INFO  org.dspace.event.EventServiceImpl @ EventService dispatcher pool initialized
2017-05-30 16:58:32,839 INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version @ HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
2017-05-30 16:58:32,845 INFO  org.hibernate.Version @ HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.21.Final}
2017-05-30 16:58:32,847 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment @ HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-30 16:58:32,848 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment @ HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-05-30 16:58:32,873 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration @ HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:/dspace/config/hibernate.cfg.xml
2017-05-30 16:58:32,926 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration @ HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
2017-05-30 16:58:33,109 INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect @ HHH000400: Using dialect: org.dspace.storage.rdbms.hibernate.postgres.DSpacePostgreSQL82Dialect
2017-05-30 16:58:33,122 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder @ HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-05-30 16:58:33,130 INFO  org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry @ HHH000270: Type registration [pg-uuid] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@765f490b
2017-05-30 16:58:33,131 INFO  org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry @ HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4c1e9e97
2017-05-30 16:58:33,389 WARN  org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass @ HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): org.dspace.eperson.Group2GroupCache
2017-05-30 16:58:33,390 WARN  org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass @ HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): org.dspace.checker.MostRecentChecksum
2017-05-30 16:58:33,390 WARN  org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass @ HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): org.dspace.checker.MostRecentChecksum
2017-05-30 16:58:33,396 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator @ HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2017-05-30 16:58:33,401 INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory @ HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-05-30 16:58:33,442 WARN  net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory @ No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/dspace/webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
2017-05-30 16:58:33,451 WARN  net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager @ Creating a new instance of CacheManager using the diskStorePath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.68\temp " which is already used by an existing CacheManager.
The source of the configuration was net.sf.ehcache.config.generator.ConfigurationSource$DefaultConfigurationSource@33e55fd5.
The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.68\temp \ehcache_auto_created_1496174313451.
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
2017-05-30 16:58:33,452 INFO  org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache @ HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
2017-05-30 16:58:33,455 WARN  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory @ HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
2017-05-30 16:58:33,466 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration @ HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:/dspace/config/hibernate.cfg.xml
2017-05-30 16:58:33,471 INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration @ HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
2017-05-30 16:58:33,478 INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect @ HHH000400: Using dialect: org.dspace.storage.rdbms.hibernate.postgres.DSpacePostgreSQL82Dialect
2017-05-30 16:58:33,478 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder @ HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-05-30 16:58:33,478 INFO  org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry @ HHH000270: Type registration [pg-uuid] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@765f490b
2017-05-30 16:58:33,479 INFO  org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry @ HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4c1e9e97
2017-05-30 16:58:33,513 WARN  org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass @ HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): org.dspace.eperson.Group2GroupCache
2017-05-30 16:58:33,514 WARN  org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass @ HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): org.dspace.checker.MostRecentChecksum
2017-05-30 16:58:33,514 WARN  org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass @ HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): org.dspace.checker.MostRecentChecksum
2017-05-30 16:58:33,515 INFO  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator @ HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2017-05-30 16:58:33,515 INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory @ HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-05-30 16:58:33,515 WARN  net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory @ No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/dspace/webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
2017-05-30 16:58:33,519 WARN  net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager @ Creating a new instance of CacheManager using the diskStorePath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.68\temp " which is already used by an existing CacheManager.
The source of the configuration was net.sf.ehcache.config.generator.ConfigurationSource$DefaultConfigurationSource@33e55fd5.
The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.68\temp \ehcache_auto_created_1496174313519.
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
2017-05-30 16:58:33,519 INFO  org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache @ HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
2017-05-30 16:58:33,519 WARN  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory @ HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
```

**2017-05-30 16:58:33,521 FATAL org.dspace.core.Context @ Cannot obtain the bean which provides a database connection. Check previous entries in the dspace.log to find why the db failed to initialize.**

**I tested the connection via command line and it works.**

```
dspace\bin>dspace database test
Using DSpace installation in: \dspace

Attempting to connect to database
Connected successfully!
Database Type: postgres
Database URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dspace
Database Schema: extensions
Database Username: dspace
Database Software: PostgreSQL version 9.4.5
Database Driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver version PostgreSQL 9.4.1211
PostgreSQL 'pgcrypto' extension installed/up-to-date? true (version=1.1)
```

**

**How to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while so I don't recall precisely, but I vaguely remember having a similar problem due to lack of memory allocated to java. Maybe you can try to increase your memory allocation in your java opts and see if it gives better results ?

Good luck

Comment: I increased the memory of the java but the problem continues.